# Centos device /dev/sdb1 is not a valid luks device?

Tags: centos, filesystems, luks

I have Centos on Virtualbox, when I installed Centos I used all 20G. After installation I made extend for more one driver with 5G inside Centos everything is good when I made partitions and file system. But when I tried cryptsetup on that extend driver I got this message:

```
Device /dev/sdb1 is not a valid LUKS device
```

, Any help for this problem.

Comment: What command did you enter, what did you expect to happen, what did actually happen? The error message seems to indicate that you did not do `cryptsetup luksFormat`, but without basic information how can anybody help you?

Comment: I was able to execute without error: "cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb1"

,the error message here: "cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 secret"
, And I want to write to /dev/mapper/secret then close luks.